# window.location inside knockoutjs viewmodel not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I have the following:

**HTML**

```
<div id="documentsList" data-bind="foreach: documents">
   <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-document" data-bind="click: $root.onViewDocumentClick"></span>
</div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
documentViewModel = new function() {
   var self = this;
   self.documents = ko.observableArray([]); //Loaded elsewhere
   self.onViewDocumentClick = function(data) {
      var path = "/ViewDocument/0";
      var url = path.replace("/0","/" + data.Id.ToString());
      window.location = url;
   }
}

$(function() {
   $ko.applyBindings(documentViewModel,$("#documentsList")[0]);
  });
```

My problem is that, once the documents are loaded and I click the icon, the page reload happens but it shows that the page is actually trying to reload /ViewDocument/undefined
... which of course raises an error because the page doesn't exist.

If I make the following changes to handle the click event through jQuery rather than Knockout, then things work fine.

**HTML**

```
<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-document" data-bind="text: Id"></span>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
$("#documentsList").on("click","span.ui-icon-document",function() {
      var path = "/ViewDocument/0";
      var url = path.replace("/0","/" + $(this).text());
      window.location = url;
});
```

What am I missing?

**EDIT**
Here is a fiddle to demo my problem: [Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/LzFx6/2/)
If you change the name of the div to documentList2 you'll see the correct behavior.  If you leave it documentList, you'll see the error. **Be sure to Run after you change the div name**

Comment: `window.location` is not your problem.  It would seem that `data.Id.ToString()` is returning `undefined`.

Comment: No, my objects within the array are not observables and do not have observable properties.  See the fiddle above.

Comment: Your fiddle seems to work fine before, especially if I change the URL to use `data.id`, as that is the part that has the path: http://jsfiddle.net/jtbowden/CQS5q/1/

Comment: Sorry, I was in a hurry before lunch.  Here is an updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LzFx6/3/ .  Items in the top list return an error.  Items in the bottom list work.  (Running in Chrome)

Comment: I still don't understand why you are using `data.name`.  `data.name` contains "Fiddle 1" and "Fiddle 2", which is not what you want.  You want `data.id`.

Comment: Sorry, you're right.  I didn't catch that in your first comment.  Funny, it seems to work ... so there must be something odd about the rest of my page that is causing a problem.  Thanks for your help.  Still not sure what is going on in my dev environment though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I had two other click bindings on the documentList element (tied to other sub-elements).  However, these were firing before window.location took effect.  So, by the time window.location was able to execute, the url var was out of scope.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that `Id` is defined in your documents object?  The `/ViewDocument/undefined` seems to indicate that `data.Id.ToString()` is resolving to `undefined`.

I put together a fiddle here that seems to work fine when I define `Id` in the document object:

http://jsfiddle.net/jtbowden/gf9QT/

I commented out the `window.location` line for obvious reasons, but I can clearly see in my debug console that it is trying to access the correct URL.

Comment: Id is definitely defined.  I've stepped through debugger (chrome) and added an alert immediately before window.location to display the value of url and it displays properly.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it is a typo, but it is "toString()" not "ToString"

```
var url = path.replace("/0","/" + data.Id.ToString());
```

should be

```
var url = path.replace("/0","/" + data.Id.toString());
```